# Output on one command cause next one to fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Hi i have following script

```
winrs -r:test.one.two -u:test -p:'te$st' echo %computername%

winrs -r:test2.one.two -u:test -p:'te$st' echo %computername%

winrs -r:test3.one.two -u:test -p:'te$st' echo %computername%
```

I have following problem, if  first `winrs` command fails with reason `cannot resolve host name` or result is different then expected computer name for example empty line. Next command also fails, is there way to prevent such behaviour? Ignore output or redirect it to the other (but also visible) stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `& cmd /c "winrs -r:test.one.two -u:test -p:'te$st' echo %computername% 2>&1"` to redirect the error and later you can use try catch on each level.

```
try
{
    try
    {
    & cmd /c "winrs -r:test.one.two -u:test -p:'te$st' echo %computername% 2>&1"
    }
    catch
    {
    "1st winrs failed"
    }
    try
    {
    & cmd /c "winrs -r:test2.one.two -u:test -p:'te$st' echo %computername% 2>&1"
    }
    catch
    {
    "2nd winrs failed"
    }
    try
    {
    & cmd /c "winrs -r:test3.one.two -u:test -p:'te$st' echo %computername% 2>&1"
    }
    catch
    {
    "3rd winrs failed"
    }
}
catch
{
"Entire Script failed"
}
```

hope it helps.